# Resource Allocation w/ Dynamic Programming Algorithm

Tags: java, algorithm, dynamic

Given a set of functions f1...fn (discrete time) and a time limit (int), should find the maximum output i.e. allocate time across different functions to maximize the sum of the used functions' outputs.

For any function, the value at any time represents the total output for the function if used for a said time. i.e. F(2) = total output of the function if used for 2 seconds. NOT F(1) + F(2).

All values (time, function outputs) are ints.

My current algorithm finds the max out of the possible damages by checking F(t) for the case where all time was put into one function, compares that max to the max of all possible outputs from the previous max M(t-1) + adding 1 second to each possible function (with a record of functions already used and times).

public int computeDamage() {

```
    int totalTime = calculator.getTotalTime();
    int numAttacks = calculator.getNumAttacks();

    if(totalTime == 0) return 0;

    int[] attackHist = new int[numAttacks];

    return maxDamage(numAttacks, attackHist, 1, totalTime, 0);

}

public int maxDamage(int numAttacks, int[] attackHist, int start, int end, int max) {
    //get the max of all the values at f(start), save the attack
    int maxF = -1, attack = -1;
    for(int i = 0; i < numAttacks; i++) {
        int dam = calculator.calculateDamage(i, start);
        if(dam > maxF) {
            maxF = dam;
            attack = i;
        }
    }

    //if start isn't 1, get the max of all possible values added to the attackHist
    int maxH = -1, attackH = -1;
    if(start > 1) {
        for(int j = 0; j < numAttacks; j++) {
            int dChange = -1;
            if(attackHist[j] > 0) dChange = calculator.calculateDamage(j, attackHist[j]+1) - calculator.calculateDamage(j, attackHist[j]);
            else dChange = calculator.calculateDamage(j, attackHist[j]+1);

            if((max + dChange) > maxH) {
                maxH = max + dChange;
                attackH = j;
            }
        }

        //if max is greater, reset attackHist. Otherwise, add 1 to used attack
        if(maxF > maxH) {
            Arrays.fill(attackHist, 0);
            attackHist[attack] = start;
            max = maxF;
        } else {
            attackHist[attackH]++;
            max = maxH;
        }

    } else {
        //just set the max to maxF
        max = maxF;
        attackHist[attack] = 1;

    }

    if(end == start) return max;
    else return maxDamage(numAttacks, attackHist, start+1, end, max);
}
```

For input 12.in

```
20 12
0 3 4 7 9 12 12 14 15 15 17 19
2 5 6 9 11 12 15 15 16 19 21 22
1 4 6 8 9 11 13 14 16 18 21 22
1 4 4 4 5 5 6 8 9 11 12 14
0 3 4 5 7 10 12 13 15 17 20 20
1 3 5 5 8 10 10 12 14 15 16 18
1 1 3 5 7 8 10 11 11 13 14 16
1 1 2 2 2 3 6 7 10 11 11 12
1 3 5 5 7 7 8 11 11 12 14 16
0 1 4 5 6 9 10 11 12 12 15 18
3 5 5 7 8 10 12 12 14 15 15 16
3 5 6 9 12 12 13 14 15 18 21 21
1 2 3 4 7 9 10 12 12 15 18 18
3 4 5 7 8 10 12 13 13 16 17 20
3 5 7 7 10 11 14 16 17 18 21 23
0 1 4 7 7 8 10 12 13 13 14 16
2 3 3 6 8 9 12 15 17 18 20 21
0 2 3 3 6 8 9 10 13 15 17 17
1 2 4 7 9 9 9 11 14 14 17 19
3 5 6 7 10 11 12 12 13 16 17 19
```

The first line tells how many functions (20) and how much time (12 seconds) to maximize output.

Each line is a function defined from 1 to 12 F(t) detailing how much damage the function does IN TOTAL up to that point.

The output should be 31, but my code is outputting 30.

Comment: I can't fix the delineation in the input so here is a pastebin https://pastebin.com/x7uUNjSj for my input

Comment: I fixed the input for you.  You just have to quote it as code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I won't try to debug your code, but I'll let you know exactly what it should be doing.

What you need to do is create a table of, by function, by time, `(best_value, time_this_function)`.  With your input, here is that table:

```
[[(0, 1), (3, 2), (4, 3), (7, 4), (9, 5), (12, 6), (12, 7), (14, 8), (15, 9), (15, 10), (17, 11), (19, 12)],
 [(2, 1), (5, 2), (6, 3), (9, 4), (11, 5), (12, 6), (15, 7), (17, 2), (18, 3), (21, 4), (23, 5), (24, 6)],
 [(2, 0), (5, 0), (6, 3), (9, 0), (11, 0), (13, 2), (15, 0), (17, 0), (19, 2), (21, 0), (23, 0), (25, 2)],
 [(2, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (9, 0), (11, 0), (13, 0), (15, 0), (17, 0), (19, 0), (21, 0), (23, 0), (25, 0)],
 [(2, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (9, 0), (11, 0), (13, 0), (15, 0), (17, 0), (19, 0), (21, 0), (23, 0), (25, 0)],
 [(2, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (9, 0), (11, 0), (13, 0), (15, 0), (17, 0), (19, 0), (21, 0), (23, 0), (25, 0)],
 [(2, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (9, 0), (11, 0), (13, 0), (15, 0), (17, 0), (19, 0), (21, 0), (23, 0), (25, 0)],
 [(2, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (9, 0), (11, 0), (13, 0), (15, 0), (17, 0), (19, 0), (21, 0), (23, 0), (25, 0)],
 [(2, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (9, 0), (11, 0), (13, 0), (15, 0), (17, 0), (19, 0), (21, 0), (23, 0), (25, 0)],
 [(2, 0), (5, 0), (6, 0), (9, 0), (11, 0), (13, 0), (15, 0), (17, 0), (19, 0), (21, 0), (23, 0), (25, 0)],
 [(3, 1), (5, 2), (8, 1), (10, 2), (12, 1), (14, 1), (16, 1), (18, 1), (20, 1), (22, 1), (24, 1), (26, 1)],
 [(3, 1), (6, 1), (8, 0), (11, 1), (13, 1), (15, 1), (17, 1), (20, 5), (22, 5), (24, 5), (26, 5), (28, 5)],
 [(3, 0), (6, 0), (8, 0), (11, 0), (13, 0), (15, 0), (17, 0), (20, 0), (22, 0), (24, 0), (26, 0), (28, 0)],
 [(3, 1), (6, 0), (9, 1), (11, 0), (14, 1), (16, 1), (18, 1), (20, 0), (23, 1), (25, 1), (27, 1), (29, 1)],
 [(3, 1), (6, 0), (9, 0), (12, 1), (14, 0), (17, 1), (19, 1), (21, 1), (23, 0), (26, 1), (28, 1), (30, 1)],
 [(3, 0), (6, 0), (9, 0), (12, 0), (14, 0), (17, 0), (19, 0), (21, 0), (23, 0), (26, 0), (28, 0), (30, 0)],
 [(3, 0), (6, 0), (9, 0), (12, 0), (14, 0), (17, 0), (19, 0), (21, 0), (23, 0), (26, 0), (28, 0), (30, 0)],
 [(3, 0), (6, 0), (9, 0), (12, 0), (14, 0), (17, 0), (19, 0), (21, 0), (23, 0), (26, 0), (28, 0), (30, 0)],
 [(3, 0), (6, 0), (9, 0), (12, 0), (14, 0), (17, 0), (19, 0), (21, 0), (23, 0), (26, 0), (28, 0), (30, 0)],
 [(3, 1), (6, 0), (9, 0), (12, 0), (15, 1), (17, 0), (20, 1), (22, 1), (24, 1), (26, 0), (29, 1), (31, 1)]]
```

And once you have that table, you need to just walk from the last entry backwards to figure out the path.

The times spent on each function, from last to first, are:

```
(31, 1) => 1
(28, 0) => 0
(28, 0) => 0
(28, 0) => 0
(28, 0) => 0
(28, 1) => 1
(25, 1) => 1
(22, 0) => 0
(22, 5) => 5
(10, 2) => 2
(5, 0)  => 0
(5, 0)  => 0
(5, 0)  => 0
(5, 0)  => 0
(5, 0)  => 0
(5, 0)  => 0
(5, 0)  => 0
(5, 0)  => 0
(5, 2)  => 2
# At this point we back up out of our table, and we spent no time on the first.
```

Reversing that we get `2` on the second function, `2` on the 11th, `5` on the 12th, `1` on the 14th, `1` on the 15th, and 1 on the last.

Hopefully that helps you track down which step you are missing.

Comment: Seems like the time complexity for making the table is much greater than polynomial on time and number of functions. For a given entry in the table, it seems like you have to consider all possible combinations of all previous functions/times in order to create possible sequences and determine if their outputs are greater than the max when you consider putting all time into a single function for all previous functions. In some of the cases, you end up decreasing the time you put into a function. Just not picking up an intuitive sense of filling out the table that won't blow up with larger input

Comment: @Vice Nope.  For `n` functions with time `m` the total size of the table is `O(n*m)` and the time to produce it is `O(n*m^2)`.  So it is polynomial.

Comment: What's the recursive form for finding each entry?

Comment: The form for the entries after the first row (which is just the value of the function at that time for that time) is the max of the previous row up to that time where the value being maxed (previous(t).max + current(T)) and t + T = time. I understand the complexity being O(n * m^2) now. Marked as answer.